# ERD diagram design issues

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, erd

I confuse about erd relationship like have 3 role which are admin, restaurant owner and user.  My project is find nearby restaurants. I plan to do admin can add restaurant  and restaurant owner then each restaurant owner can login to their dashboard for manage their  restaurant info . How can i design erd diagram?

Comment: Why not have only table users and column for user type?

Comment: One user to many restaurants?

Comment: ERD diagram is for planning database, right? Your question doesn't say anything about restaurants or anything else - just 3 types of users.
With this information I propose you one table for USERS, and you can store many users in one table. Maybe provide your proposition of EDR, so we would know what you want.

Comment: I plan to do admin can add restaurant and restaurant owner then each restaurant owner can login to their dashboard for manage their restaurant info .

Comment: My project find nearby restaurants

Comment: I'd start with a pen and a piece of paper

Answer (score 1):

You have users (admins and restaurant owners), restaurants and user roles. Each user has one role and each restaurant has one user (owner). Not every user owns a restaurant, so keep that in mind.